# How to specify a comment for the detailed info in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am asking here how to write a comment in a dockerfile. So I need to be clear that I am not talking about writing

```
#This is a comment
```

into a dockerfile.

What I am looking for is how to set the comment field in the detailed description.

```
docker inspect ubuntu -f {{.Comment}}
docker inspect ubuntu
```

with either of these two commands you can see a comment entry in the detailed description. The current ubuntu container has an empty comment.

I checked the [builder reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and did not find anything about it.
I googled and stack-overflowed - unfortunately the keyword "comment" leads the search towards how to use `#comment` which is not what I am after.

My question is how can I populate a comment field in the detailed description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `docker commit` command. See docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/):

```
$ docker pull nginx
$ docker image inspect -f {{.Comment}} nginx

$ docker run -d --name mycontainer nginx
$ docker commit -m "my comment" mycontainer nginx
$ docker image inspect -f {{.Comment}} nginx
my comment
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is saved for the underlying tools to manage. It's part of the [layer history spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/v1.0.1/specs-go/v1/config.go#L74):

```
// History describes the history of a layer.
type History struct {
    // Created is the combined date and time at which the layer was created, formatted as defined by RFC 3339, section 5.6.
    Created *time.Time `json:"created,omitempty"`

    // CreatedBy is the command which created the layer.
    CreatedBy string `json:"created_by,omitempty"`

    // Author is the author of the build point.
    Author string `json:"author,omitempty"`

    // Comment is a custom message set when creating the layer.
    Comment string `json:"comment,omitempty"`

    // EmptyLayer is used to mark if the history item created a filesystem diff.
    EmptyLayer bool `json:"empty_layer,omitempty"`
}
```

You'll see that layer history in the `docker image history`, and the `docker image inspect` appears to pull the value from the last layer.

Some tools like [buildkit it gets set to a hardcoded value](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v19.03.12/builder/builder-next/exporter/writer.go#L124):

```
if len(diffs) > historyLayers {
    // some history items are missing. add them based on the ref metadata
    for _, md := range refMeta[historyLayers:] {
        history = append(history, ocispec.History{
            Created:   &md.createdAt,
            CreatedBy: md.description,
            Comment:   "buildkit.exporter.image.v0",
        })
    }
}
```

With a Dockerfile built by the classic `docker build` command, I'm not aware of any way to set this Comment field on the individual steps.

As mentioned by Rajesh, you can set the comment with the `docker commit` command which I don't recommend using for any images going to production since the image needs to be manually created in an error prone method.

---

Instead, the typical way to add metadata to a docker image is to set a [label in the Dockefile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label).

```
LABEL "com.example.vendor"="ACME Incorporated"
LABEL com.example.label-with-value="foo"
LABEL version="1.0"
LABEL description="This text illustrates \
that label-values can span multiple lines."
```

These labels are also copied into the container metadata when it's spawned from that image, and they are inherited from the parent image (set in your `FROM` line) so be sure to replace the label in child images to avoid confusion.